# installing Chorus's GreenPlum on OSX

Tags: macos, hadoop, bigdata, greenplum

I am trying to install Chorus on OSX. So I need to install `GreenPlum` as described [here](https://github.com/Chorus/chorus/wiki/Getting-started-with-Chorus-development#user-content-download-greenplum-db). The doc says that I have to download the `GreenPLum` database and extract the `greenplum-db-4.2.5.0.tar.gz` tar file. So I went to the dedicated site `[Pivotal][2]`. This file provides some `.bin` file, but when I execute it I get the message `Installer will only install on RedHat/CentOS x86_64`. The execution of this file supposes that it provides the mentionned tar file.

So I deduce that I must get some `OSX` dedicated file, but the `Pivotal` documentation says that the tar file should be extracted (only in development mode). Perhaps I am running some wrong commands. Could someone help ?

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://network.pivotal.io/products/pivotal-gpdb#files to get the actual installers you'll need for OSX. Be aware that the community edition may not support everything.

Comment: thank you for your response. Indeed, I found an installer but it is not compatible with the `Chorus` installer. Do you think I can find the `greenplum-db-4.2.5.0.tar.gz` version archive